# Can I download the underlying Java(TM) Platform SE Binary file

Tags: java, decompiler

I open a .jar file then enter credentials and click run.

Then a new program is opened. I want to decompile *this* .jar file with JD-GUI but I have no way of downloading it.  It is essentially a jar game file that I want to modify the code inside. Is this even possible?

[image: Image of what I am referring to: The V236 program.]

Comment: Why do you think there is downloading involved? Are you having issues finding the location of the jar being run on your system?

Comment: I have no issues decompiling the initial .jar file, that is just the client screen and launcher to what I actually want to decompile. What I want is after that, when you click "Play Now" and it opens a brand new jar. The stuff I decompiled from the original jar does not contain anything useful - that info would be in the new jar.

Comment: That likely means it is starting a new process from the initial application. If you right click the "Name", "Status", etc bar you can enable "Command Line". This shows you the command used to run each process. That should show you where the jar is located and how the program was started.

Comment: Thank you! That solved my issue! It was hidden pretty well but that trick helped me find the .jar file that I needed!